# package com.google.gson does not exist

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm working with the following programs: Specifically Tomcat 8, VirtualBox virtual machine, & Gson 2.3.1

I'm trying to test out a method in Gson that allows you marshall/unmarshall Java objects into the JSON format.

This is the code I am using this for (in order for it to compile properly, both classes of java code need to be compiling at the same time...:

Most importantly is my code for testing the JSON conversion method:

```
package com.cs330;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

    public class IngredientProto 
    {
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
         Ingredient neo = new Ingredient(6, "cheddar cheese", "cheese");

         System.out.println("Object confirmed: " + neo.toString());

         //New GSON object for marshalling...
         Gson neoIngredient = new Gson();

         //Use said object to create the JSON formatted String for this Ingredient (Object).
         String jsonThis = neoIngredient.toJson(neo);

         //Printing out the new object (Ingredient)...
         System.out.println ("Object formatted to JSON: " + jsonThis);

         //Convert Back via unmarshalling. NOW!
         Ingredient orga = neoIngredient.fromJson(jsonThis, Ingredient.class);

         //Print Again!
         System.out.println("Reverting back into Object variable: " + orga.toString());
       }
      }
```

Here, for reference, is my code for the Ingredient Class I'm working with...

```
package com.cs330;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ingredient //implements Comparable<Ingredient>
{
 private int ingredientID;
 private String ingredientName;
 protected String ingredientType;

  //DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR 
  Ingredient()
  {
   this.ingredientID = 0;
   this.ingredientName = "No Ingredient";
   this.ingredientType = "No Type";
  }

  //CONSTRUCTOR 1 - Parameters for Name, ID, and Type.
  Ingredient(int ingredientID, String ingredientName, String ingredientType)
  {
   setIngredientID(ingredientID);
   setIngredientName(ingredientName);
   setIngredientType(ingredientType);
  }

  //CONSTRUCTOR 2 - Parameters for Name and Type.
  Ingredient(String ingredientName, String ingredientType)
  {
   this.ingredientID = 0;
   setIngredientName(ingredientName);
   setIngredientType(ingredientType);
  }

  //Getters and Setters Go here.

      //TO STRING
      public String toString()
      {
       String results = " ";
        results = this.ingredientID + ": " + this.ingredientName
                   + " (" + this.ingredientType + ") ";
       return results;
      }//END toSTRING

     //...Main for testing...

}//END PROGRAM
```

The errors I keep getting involve the following whenever I try to compile them in CMD on my virtual machine:

1. `error: package com.google.gson does not exist` - I have import com.google.gson.Gson where it needs to be in my program, yet I keep getting this error my code has nothing wrong with it...
2. `error: class, interface, or enum expected` - I actually add package com.google.gson, and I get this error despite everything else being right.

Both errors happen when I try to test the Gson program code out, alongside the Ingredient class I created. My real concern is how I can effectively deal with this...

Comment: 1) An `import` statement makes it possible to use a simple name of a type. It doesn't actually _import_ anything. You have to add the library to the compilation (and runtime) classpath.

Comment: 2) Please show where that occurs.

Comment: The error occurs on lines 2 and 13 of my GSON java code when I compile it in CMD. Because the code has been convinced the required GSON package to run the program doesn't exist, that means it can't find the symbols, or classes required to get methods relying on that code to work, either. That's my problem in a nutshell...

Answer (score 6):

While compiling in the Command Prompt use the -cp or -classpath to set your gson.jar in your classpath. Something like this:

```
javac -classpath <LOCATION_TO_GSON JAR FILE>  *.java
```

During the runtime check that gson library is present in your classpath (either `WEB-INF/lib`  or `\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\lib`)

Comment: I know I'm late, as I was trying to follow your perfect advice here...  I'm sure it sounds something like javac -classpath CLASSPATH%=c:\progs\tomcat8\lib\*.java OR javac -classpath CLASSPATH%=c:\progs\tomcat8\webapps\webserv1\WEB-INF\lib\*.java... Sounds legit; just a shame I keep gettign the package does not exist error, despite compiling both of my java codes I've presented at the same time...

Comment: From the comment you made, i see an issue. It should be something like this: javac -classpath %CLASSPATH%;<LOCATION_TO_GSON JAR FILE>/gson-2.3.jar  *.java

Comment: Thank you - also, sorry to respond so late (I had to work....) But I will try this.

Comment: I tried your idea - all I kept getting was an invalid flag error. What am I doing wrong here?!

Comment: Can you paste here the error please?

Comment: It reads: javac: invalid flag CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;c:\progs\jaxrsri\c:\progs\jaxrs-ri\api\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar;c:\progs\jaxrs-ri\api\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar;c:\progs\jaxrs-ri\api\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar; After that, it tells me to use -help for a list of possible options (I need real help with this code, not THIS.).

Comment: I think you are using it in a wrong way. Try this: javac -classpath %CLASSPATH%;c:\progs\jaxrsri\c:\progs\jaxrs-ri\api\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0??.1.jar;c:\progs\jaxrs-ri\api\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar;c:\progs\jaxrs-ri\api\java??x.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar; *.java

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - I needed to set my classpath to something similar in my virtual machine: c:\progs; c:\progs\jaxrs-ri\api\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar; c:\progs\jaxrs-ri\api\mysql-connector-java-5.1.32-bin.jar; c:\progs\com\cs330\; c:\progs\jaxrs-ri\api\gson-2.3.1.jar; c:\progs\tomcat8\webapps\webserv1\WEB-INF\classes. I got this from a fellow classmate and it worked after setting it all to the classpath for compiliation. Thank you for the advice, otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

You need the Gson jar file in the [Tomcat classpath](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath) during runtime and in the [classpath of your development environment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) for compilation.

Comment: you were right all along - but I also needed a gson jar file in c:\progs... Everything started working. I also took your advice in put the gson in my main lib in tomcat8 and in my webserv1/lib folder on my virtual machine. Managed to work there, too. Thanks for that.

Comment: specific example for osx (probably linux too): go to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson and download the latest jar (into the same folder you will be in when you run javac) e.g. at http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.6.2/gson-2.6.2.jar, then compile with ```javac -classpath "`pwd`/`ls gson*.jar`" mycode.java```